# Remove class and add class

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript and CSS3 responsive HTML menu for mobile devices. The JS is quite simple. It gets the element ID of the body and if the menu is closed it changes class to menuOpen, and vice versa. The CSS handles all the transitions and displays of the actual menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function menuButton() {
        if( document.getElementById("htmlbody").className == "menuClosed" ) {
            document.getElementById("htmlbody").className = "menuOpen";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("htmlbody").className = "menuClosed";
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem I ran into is this. Instead of removing the entire class and replacing the entire class, how can I remove a single class and then add a single class?

Since an element will contain multiple classes I need to change the condition to see IF it contains the className, as opposed to being the actual className. I believe I can simply add the new class by doing the JS below but I don't know how to remove the old class.

```
document.getElementById("htmlbody").className += "menuOpen";
```

Hope I've provided enough details.

**EDIT**

Thanks for help. I've managed to get this to work great. Does just what I need to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function menuButton() {
        var htmlBody = document.getElementById("htmlbody");

        if( htmlBody.classList.contains("menuClosed") ) {
            htmlBody.className = htmlBody.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)menuClosed(?=\s|$)/g, " menuOpen");
        } else {
            htmlBody.className = htmlBody.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)menuOpen(?=\s|$)/g, " menuClosed");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check out the `classList` API - http://html5doctor.com/the-classlist-api/. Also, why call `getElementById` so many times? Just call it once and save the element in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use regular expressions for this.  I have a macro that does the following

```
(node).className = (node).className.replace(/(?:^|\s)cl(?=\s|$)/g,"");
```

where cl is replaced with the actual class to be removed.  That handles the remove.  You can code your insert as you said but be aware your className can grow as you get duplicate class invocations.

Comment: Does this account for spaces? for example, if you have `class1 class2 class3` and remove class2 will it remove the extra whitespace? Just curious cause I do mine a similar way but with an extra replace to get rid of white spaces. Would be cool to only have 1 replace

Comment: Yes.  It expects a class name to be preceded by either a space (\s) or the beginning of string (^) and ended by a space or end of string ($).  But, it may leave an extra space in the className (as I read the rest of your question).

Comment: Would upvote if I could. The expression worked great. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Function Definition**

```
Node.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
            if (this.classList) {
                return this.classList.contains(className);
            } else {
                return (-1 < this.className.indexOf(className));
            }
        };




Node.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
    if (this.classList) {
        this.classList.add(className);
    } else if (!this.hasClass(className)) {
        var classes = this.className.split(" ");
        classes.push(className);
        this.className = classes.join(" ");
    }
    return this;
};

Node.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    if (this.classList) {
        this.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
        var classes = this.className.split(" ");
        classes.splice(classes.indexOf(className), 1);
        this.className = classes.join(" ");
    }
    return this;
};
```

**Usage :**

```
myElement =  document.getElementById("htmlbody");
```

Now you can call `myElement.removeClass('myClass')`

or chain it: `myElement.removeClass("oldClass").addClass("newClass");`

**This will remove a single class**

Comment: OP is targeting mobile devices which should all support `classList` (with the exception of Opera mini). I don't think you need the shims but nice work anyway :)

Comment: Hey, maybe OP needs to cover Opera mini. I'm curious about the downvote too. No explanation is poor form

Answer (score 0):

```
   function menuButton() {
        var htmlBody = document.getElementById('htmlbody');
        if( htmlBody.className.test(/menuClosed/)) {
            htmlBody.className.replace('menuClosed', 'menuOpen');
        } else if (htmlBody.className.test(/menuOpen/)){
            htmlBody.className.replace('menuOpen', 'menuClosed');;
        }
    }
```

Use the String.replace function. And i sugest to use class names as -. Not camel cased as is not the standard, but it depends of your team.

Comment: There is no standard for class names regarding hyphens vs camel case so why bother mentioning it?

Comment: Yes, is more wide use hyphens. It makes the html more redeable. I see camel cased classes on legacy code. This is because i mentioned

Comment: Helped quite a bit. Would upvote you if I could. Using the replace worked good as you suggested and I shortened code using var htmlBody.

Comment: You're welcome. Is a good practice to keep your dom elements in a variable so you don't need to parse the dom for the same object.